# Why does the mouse cursor jump when at right edge of screen, causing strange application behavior (e.g. eclipse)?

Tags: linux, x11, nvidia, mouse, plasma

When I move my mouse to the right edge of the screen, regardless of the vertical position when entering the right edge, it jumps to a point about 25% down from the top at the right edge of the screen.

After this, I noticed strange behavior in Eclipse, where the context menus pop up in the wrong place (usually far to the left of the cursor).  The problem in Eclipse goes away after restarting Eclipse, but comes back again the first time I move to the right edge of the screen.

My system is Mageia 8, Plasma desktop, Breeze theme, Linux 5.10.41, AMD64 (Ryzen Threadripper 3960X 24-Core Processor), with with two NVIDIA GPUs (GeForce RTX 2080 SUPER), with one 4k monitor attached.

The mouse jump always occurs, and is independent of whether Eclipse is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused because my xorg.conf had two screens configured, but I had only one monitor attached.

Here is my original xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 465.24.02

# File generated by XFdrake (rev 262502)
# **********************************************************************
# Refer to the xorg.conf man page for details about the format of
# this file.
# **********************************************************************

Section "ServerLayout"

    #Option "Xinerama"
    Identifier     "layout1"
    Screen         "screen1" 0 0
    Screen         "screen2" RightOf "screen1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "v4l" # Video for Linux
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"

 # allows the server to start up even if the mouse does not work
    #DontZoom # disable <Ctrl><Alt><KP_+>/<KP_-> (resolution switching)
    Option         "allowmouseopenfail"
    Option         "DontZap" "False" # disable <Ctrl><Alt><BS> (server abort)
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from data in "/etc/sysconfig/keyboard"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # Apple iMac modes
    Identifier     "monitor1"
    VendorName     "Plug'n Play"
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 78.525 1024 1049 1145 1312 768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 62.357 800 821 901 1040 600 601 604 632 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "640x480" 49.886 640 661 725 832 480 481 484 514 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "832x624" 57 832 876 940 1152 624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 100 800 816 824 840 600 616 624 640 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1152x768" 78.741 1152 1173 1269 1440 768 769 772 800 +vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 65 1024 1032 1176 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 65 1024 1048 1184 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 112.62 1024 1076 1248 1420 768 768 780 808 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1280x1024" 135 1280 1288 1392 1664 1024 1027 1030 1064
    ModeLine       "1280x1024" 134.989 1280 1317 1429 1688 1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "768x576" 50.00 768 832 846 1000 576 590 595 630
    ModeLine       "768x576" 63.07 768 800 960 1024 576 578 590 616
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # Apple iMac modes
    Identifier     "monitor2"
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 78.525 1024 1049 1145 1312 768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 62.357 800 821 901 1040 600 601 604 632 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "640x480" 49.886 640 661 725 832 480 481 484 514 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "832x624" 57 832 876 940 1152 624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 100 800 816 824 840 600 616 624 640 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1152x768" 78.741 1152 1173 1269 1440 768 769 772 800 +vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 65 1024 1032 1176 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 65 1024 1048 1184 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 112.62 1024 1076 1248 1420 768 768 780 808 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1280x1024" 135 1280 1288 1392 1664 1024 1027 1030 1064
    ModeLine       "1280x1024" 134.989 1280 1317 1429 1688 1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "768x576" 50.00 768 832 846 1000 576 590 595 630
    ModeLine       "768x576" 63.07 768 800 960 1024 576 578 590 616
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce 635 series and later"
    BusID          "PCI:33:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce 635 series and later"
    BusID          "PCI:74:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "screen1"
    Device         "device1"
    Monitor        "monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "DPMS"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "nvidia-auto-select"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "screen2"
    Device         "device2"
    Monitor        "monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "DPMS"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "nvidia-auto-select"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

If I comment out the second `Screen` in the `ServerLayout` section, and comment out the second `Screen` section definition at the end, the issue is resolved (after a reboot).  The mouse no longer jumps at the edge, and Eclipse context menus always pop up under the cursor.

This xorg.conf file was created by the NVIDIA driver installer.

Here is the new xorg.conf file that works:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 465.24.02

# File generated by XFdrake (rev 262502)
# **********************************************************************
# Refer to the xorg.conf man page for details about the format of
# this file.
# **********************************************************************

Section "ServerLayout"

    #Option "Xinerama"
    Identifier     "layout1"
    Screen         "screen1" 0 0
#    Screen         "screen2" RightOf "screen1"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "v4l" # Video for Linux
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"

 # allows the server to start up even if the mouse does not work
    #DontZoom # disable <Ctrl><Alt><KP_+>/<KP_-> (resolution switching)
    Option         "allowmouseopenfail"
    Option         "DontZap" "False" # disable <Ctrl><Alt><BS> (server abort)
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from data in "/etc/sysconfig/keyboard"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
    Option         "XkbLayout" "us"
    Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # Apple iMac modes
    Identifier     "monitor1"
    VendorName     "Plug'n Play"
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 78.525 1024 1049 1145 1312 768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 62.357 800 821 901 1040 600 601 604 632 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "640x480" 49.886 640 661 725 832 480 481 484 514 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "832x624" 57 832 876 940 1152 624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 100 800 816 824 840 600 616 624 640 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1152x768" 78.741 1152 1173 1269 1440 768 769 772 800 +vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 65 1024 1032 1176 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 65 1024 1048 1184 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 112.62 1024 1076 1248 1420 768 768 780 808 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1280x1024" 135 1280 1288 1392 1664 1024 1027 1030 1064
    ModeLine       "1280x1024" 134.989 1280 1317 1429 1688 1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "768x576" 50.00 768 832 846 1000 576 590 595 630
    ModeLine       "768x576" 63.07 768 800 960 1024 576 578 590 616
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # Apple iMac modes
    Identifier     "monitor2"
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 78.525 1024 1049 1145 1312 768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 62.357 800 821 901 1040 600 601 604 632 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "640x480" 49.886 640 661 725 832 480 481 484 514 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "832x624" 57 832 876 940 1152 624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "800x600" 100 800 816 824 840 600 616 624 640 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1152x768" 78.741 1152 1173 1269 1440 768 769 772 800 +vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 65 1024 1032 1176 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 65 1024 1048 1184 1344 768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync
    ModeLine       "1024x768" 112.62 1024 1076 1248 1420 768 768 780 808 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "1280x1024" 135 1280 1288 1392 1664 1024 1027 1030 1064
    ModeLine       "1280x1024" 134.989 1280 1317 1429 1688 1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync
    ModeLine       "768x576" 50.00 768 832 846 1000 576 590 595 630
    ModeLine       "768x576" 63.07 768 800 960 1024 576 578 590 616
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce 635 series and later"
    BusID          "PCI:33:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce 635 series and later"
    BusID          "PCI:74:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "screen1"
    Device         "device1"
    Monitor        "monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "DPMS"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes      "nvidia-auto-select"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

#Section "Screen"
#    Identifier     "screen2"
#    Device         "device2"
#    Monitor        "monitor2"
#    DefaultDepth    24
#    Option         "DPMS"
#    SubSection     "Display"
#        Depth       24
#        Modes      "nvidia-auto-select"
#    EndSubSection
#EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for showing where to look to fix cursor crossing right edge of the screen. There is a simple solution:
Replace the `RightOf "screen1"` with `0 0` in definition of screen2 leaving all other untouched. You can use your favorite text editor to do this (I use gedit) but remember you have to be superuser. CLI command is:
`$ sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf` then find, replace, save and reboot.